# refused to display in a frame(set X-Frame-Option' to SAMEORIGIN)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe, same-origin-policy

I am trying to embed a google(https://www.google.com) into an iframe but it show's **frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'**. If there is an error X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' i need to show a button as "Click hear to launch in new window". I am using HTML and Jquery.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: check the iframe length

Comment: Google (and most domains, if they are properly configured) will set the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header to disallow the site from being shown in an `iframe` on an external site for very obvious security reasons. There is nothing you can do to stop this.